# Hide data points in Excel if #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts, vba

I have a chart in Excel

[image]

based on the data

[image]

My problem is that I want to hide the data point at #N/A.

The use case is that sometimes there will be a country, but I want the user to be able to disable/enable each country and I want the chart to dynamically respond to the changes.

So instead of having all the data points, I want it, in this example, to have only 3 data points.

Comment: Does =iferror() work? Or ifna(), I think it's called that...

Comment: But I don't want to decide whether a cell has `NA()`. I just want to exclude them from my Chart, so in the example above, I only want to show Germany, France, and UK (and not the NA() data point)

Comment: Yes and with =iferror("your formula", "")  the cell will be left blank if there is an error in the formula. What does that do with your chart? Does that remove the datapoint or will it create a blank datapoint in the chart?

Comment: I added the `NA()` myself because I thought it would work. Leaving it blank will just create a blank data point in the chart.

Comment: Have you searches SO before posting this? See this thread for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013911/creating-a-chart-in-excel-that-ignores-n-a-or-blank-cells

Comment: Your chart should respond to filters on the underlying table (and if your data isnt formatted as a table, it should be). You can then add a slicer, and filter out (or to) anything you prefer. Try formatting your data as a table, then create a chart from that table (Insert > Charts > Line Chart). You can add a slicer by going to Insert > Slicer and selecting the category you want to slice. You can also skip the slicer and directly filter the table using the dropdown filters.

Answer (score 0):

What about turning your chart into a Pivotchart, allowing you to unfilter values which equal #N/A?

1. Select the table, Insert > Pivot table.
2. Create the chart, select the Pivot Table as the source
3. Filter out #N/A in the chart, or table

Hope this helps

Comment: No need for a pivottable in this case. A plain table will do (and is more closely aligned with the OP's need).