# Excel ignore empty cell in data for a chart

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 365. I have a data sheet with no formulas - the data is input manually. A chart is then created using that data but if there are any empty cells the chart defaults to 0 instead of simply ending at the last piece of data that was inputted. I have Googled this and know I solved the problem about 2 years ago on another chart but I can't remember what I did. It certainly wasn't a formula, as I am not using any formulas in the database. I have gone into Select Data and Hidden Data and that is on Zero but the problem still exists. Can someone help me please? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3mjm.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013911/creating-a-chart-in-excel-that-ignores-n-a-or-blank-cells is 9 years old but maybe it still contains useful advice.

Comment: Sorry no. I don't have any formulas in the sheet

Comment: Several of the answers to that question also don't have formulas, the most important being the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015251/) (sorted by score) which shows the "Hidden and empty cell settings" that influence the appearance of the chart, without any formulas being involved. However, also the first answer may be useful, it suggests to create an additional column with `IF`-formulas that computes values based on an existing column without formulas, you can do that too for your sheet.

Comment: Have tried these. Hiding rows isn't feasible and the other solution just won't work for some reason but I do appreciate your help