# Plotly: Is there a way to choose which color line takes precedence in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, bar-chart, plotly-python

I am producing horizontal stacked bar charts via plotly graph objects in python, and have one issue that I can not figure out:

The lines at the right side of the positive bar are overridden by a negative line, even when the negative value is zero.

I would prefer for a blue line to surround the positive bars, and an orange line to surround the negative bars. This works as intended until a particular group has no negative value, then an orange line appears in the right side of the plot.

I have provided enough code to reproduce the attached image as an example, and have also provided a figure which highlights the problem area (the line circled should be blue when the value of "negative" is zero).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='svg'

top_words = ['State', 'Opportunities', 'Information', 'Members', 'Enterprise', 'Affiliate', 'Networking', 'Common', 'Goals', 'Process', 'Monthly', 'Level']
neg_words = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
pos_words = [6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

font_family = "sans-serif"
font_size = 17

fig5 = go.Figure()
fig5.add_bar(
    y=top_words,
    x=pos_words,
    name='Positive',
    orientation='h',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgba(105, 149, 183, .35)',
            line=dict(color='rgba(105, 149, 183, 1)', width=2)
    )
)
fig5.add_bar(
    y=top_words,
    x=neg_words,
    name='Negative',
    orientation='h',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgba(234, 115, 11, .35)',
        line=dict(color='rgba(234, 115, 11, 1)', width=2)
    )
)
fig5.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig5.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig5.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    height=800,
    width=650,
    template='none',
    yaxis=dict(
        tickfont_family=font_family,
        tickfont_size=font_size,
        tickfont_color="#4B4D4B"
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        tickfont_family=font_family,
        tickfont_size=font_size,
        tickfont_color="#4B4D4B"
    ),
    legend=dict(
        font_size=font_size,
        font_family=font_family
    ),
    margin_pad=10,
    margin=dict(l=135, r=0, t=20, b=45)
)
fig5.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=.2, linecolor='lightgray', mirror=True)

fig5.show()
```

[image: Orange should be blue]

Thank you in advance for the help, I really tried to figure this out on my own by reading plotly documentation and scouring through stack overflow, but could not find anything on this exact topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of `0` you write `float('nan')` (or `math.nan` after importing `math`) you will not get a red line. I've adjusted this for the negative value of "Information" only to demonstrate:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='svg'

top_words = ['State', 'Opportunities', 'Information', 'Members', 'Enterprise', 'Affiliate', 'Networking', 'Common', 'Goals', 'Process', 'Monthly', 'Level']
neg_words = [0, 1, float("nan"), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
pos_words = [6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

... (rest stays the same)
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer. Thank you so much! But, I really must ask how you figured that out or where you found it. Because it is such a creative yet unexpected solution.

Comment: It reminded me of [similar behaviour of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597905/1256347) where it hides blank data if it's `NA` and I thought I would try it out here as well.